# Painting circular sections with four colors

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, recursion, coloring

The following problem is an exercise from a handout on recursion:

> The figure below shows a ring made of six small sections which you are to paint on a wall. You have four paint colors available and you will paint each of the six sections a solid color. Find the number of ways you can choose to paint the sections if no two adjacent sections can be painted with the same color.

[image: Figure]

I thought that this can be solved with simple counting. The idea is to select a section which can be painted in $4$ ways. Then the four sections taken counterclockwise can each be painted in $3$ ways. Finally, the last section can be painted in $2$ ways. So the answer would be $4\cdot3^4\cdot2=648$. But the given answer is $732$. What is wrong in my solution and what is the correct solution?

Comment: If the color of the last but one is same as the first ring then you have $3$ options for the last. Now start backtracking and it becomes clear that it gets tedious and hence the recursion

Comment: Multiple solutions: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2016_AIME_II_Problems/Problem_12

Comment: @MathLover Thanks. The link is very useful with so many solutions!

Comment: I had solved a similar problem earlier using Principle of Inclusion Exclusion. The other solutions were new to me too - I saw them today. Glad I could help.